# Character encoding of plots is broken in rstudio 1.2.5001 and in R console 3.6.1

Tags: r, plot, character-encoding

The problem is very simple and general. I just updated rstudio to the latest version and when I run a simple `plot(1)` I get the following plot. Note that this happens also on a normal console.

[image: the problem]

PS: I run on ubuntu 18.04 and R is installed with linuxbrew.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Archlinux, it had to do with the `pango` package, which updated from version 1.43 to version 1.44. This new version [removes the support for bitmap fonts](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/pango/issues/386), and somehow breaks some things.

A temporary fix that worked for me: downgrade `pango` to version 1.43.